# How do you give a text field a default font and some padding?

Tags: cocoa, textfield

What I am looking to do is change the default font of a text field and give it some padding so that when a person starts typing they will start typing further in from the edge of the text field.

Sorry, If my question is quite vague, i don't mean to be, if you need some more information just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, you can change the font of an `NSTextField` by using the `setFont:size:` method (since `NSTextField` inherits from `NSControl` - docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setFont:)):

```
NSTextField *textField;     //Pointer to your text field
...
NSFont *f = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
[textField setFont:f];
```

In answer to your second question, I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670015/nstextfield-with-padding-on-the-right) may point you in the right direction - however you will have to adapt the code to apply padding on the left-hand side of the text field rather than the right.

Comment: Where would i enter this code, should I put it into a new class file and link it up to the text field?

Comment: If the text field is created in a NIB/XIB file, then I would create a controller class for your application (unless one already exists) and implement it in the awakeFromNib function for your class (apologies, I meant to refer to the textField pointer as an outlet, perhaps I should have made that more clear); if you're creating the text field programatically then you can set the font upon creation. Of course if you are going to subclass NSTextFieldCell as shown in the link I posted then the methods for that go in your subclass's implementation file.

Comment: I see, so is as simple as just copying and pasting that code above into the controller

Comment: I meant to say, so is it as simple as just copying and pasting that code above into the controller?

Comment: Yes, to solve your question regarding setting the text field's font.

Comment: Just experimented and I made it work thanks to your code. Do you know where I should paste the code from the topic about the padding? Does it need to be in another controller?

Comment: As the user said, you need to create a class which is a  subclass of NSTextFieldCell (which controls the user interface of the text field), which is where you implement the custom behaviour of your text field that you require; take a look at the PhotoSearch example code that is posted, and also look at http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html